# Generically return a optional<T> / nullopt

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, std

I am trying to implement a generic `find_if_opt` method which is virtually identical to `std::ranges::find_if` (however it return an Optional)

So far this is my implementation.

```
    template <typename X, typename Z>
    inline auto find_if_opt(const X& ds, const Z& fn) {
        const auto it = ranges::find_if(ds, fn);
        if (it != end(ds)) {
            return std::make_optional(*it);
        }
        return {};
    }

    auto test() {
        std::vector v{1,2,3,4,5};
        return ranges::find_if_opt(v, [](auto i){
            return i == 2;
        });
    }
```

This is a part of a larger std::ranges like wrapper around c++17 algorithms. See https://godbolt.org/z/3fEe8bbh9 (for entire relevant header)

When using `{}` the compiler error is:

```
<source>:29:16: error: cannot deduce return type from initializer list
        return {};
               ^~
```

I have also tried using std::nullopt, which causes:

```
<source>:41:6:   required from here
<source>:30:21: error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'std::optional<int>' and then 'std::nullopt_t'
         return std::nullopt;
                     ^~~~~~~
```

PS: if you have suggestions regarding my ranges:: wrapper while I'm still stuck on c++17, feel free to.

Comment: A `nullopt` isn't a `std::optional`, it's a type that can be used to default construct a `std::optional`. Return `std::optional<X>{};`

Comment: Using `std::optional<X>{};` doesn't work as X is of the type of the data structure, ie X is `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ranges::range_value_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t) to get `value_type` of `X`

```
template <typename X, typename Z>
inline std::optional<std::ranges::range_value_t<X>> 
find_if_opt(const X& ds, const Z& fn) {
    const auto it = std::ranges::find_if(ds, fn);
    if (it != end(ds)) {
        return *it;
    }
    return {};
}
```

Or using [`std::iter_value_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) to get `value_type` of iterator

```
template <typename X, typename Z>
inline auto
find_if_opt(const X& ds, const Z& fn) {
    const auto it = std::ranges::find_if(ds, fn);
    if (it != end(ds)) {
        return std::make_optional(*it);
    }
    return std::optional<std::iter_value_t<decltype(it)>>{};
}
```

Or pre-C++20

```
template <typename X, typename Z>
inline auto find_if_opt(const X& ds, const Z& fn) {
  const auto it = ranges::find_if(ds, fn);
  if (it != end(ds)) {
    return std::make_optional(*it);
  }
  return std::optional<std::decay_t<decltype(*it)>>{};
}
```

Comment: Is there a c++17 way to do equivalent to `std::ranges::range_value_t`? I'm still on c++17 and this is part of a ranges like wrapper (see the godbolt link)

Comment: @Mr.Pasta: FYI: if you can't use C++20 solutions, you shouldn't tag your question with [tag:c++20].

Comment: Good point. Thanks! My thought was that the project must build with both c++17 and c++20, so I figured tagging with both made sense.

Comment: @mr.pasta I might write a helper function that takes a dereferencable and a test on it, and returns an optional.  Call it `maybe_optional`.    `return maybe_optional(it!=end(ds),it);`